# < > operators as arguments for Java program

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to run a program in Java, using:

```
java -jar lab.jar <a.json >b.json
```

If I do this like above then args.length is equal to zero. Is it possible to use those operators in command line?

Comment: Why do you need the `<` and `>`?

Comment: Do you want to use them as strngs? If that case maybe `java -jar lab.jar "<a.json" ">b.json"` will help (just a guess).

Comment: Yup, it works:). Do you think it's the only way?

Comment: The shell that you are running will interpret those as input/output redirection. You will need to escape them so the shell knows not to interpret them that way. You should be able to do quotes as @Pshemo suggested, or `\<` and `\>`, or maybe try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you sure your program is supposed to use those parameters? They are generally intended for the shell to interpret and then you can just read from `System.in` and write to `System.out`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On unixoid systems greater than and smaller than mean *I/O redirection*. So quoting them should help.